# Apache Airflow dagrun_operator in Airflow Version 1.10.10

Tags: airflow

On Migrating Airflow from V1.10.2 to V1.10.10 One of our DAG have a task which is of dagrun_operator type.

Code snippet of the task looks something as below. Please assume that DAG `dag_process_pos` exists. 
The DAG that is being triggered by the `TriggerDagRunOperator` is `dag_process_pos`. That starts with task of type `dummy_operator` [ *Just a hint if this could be the trouble maker* ]

```
task_trigger_dag_positional = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        trigger_dag_id="dag_process_pos",
        python_callable=set_up_dag_run_preprocessing,
        task_id="trigger_preprocess_dag",
        on_failure_callback=log_failure,
        execution_date=datetime.now(),
        provide_context=False,
        owner='airflow') 

def set_up_dag_run_preprocessing(context, dag_run_obj):
        ti = context['ti']
        dag_name = context['ti'].task.trigger_dag_id
        dag_run = context['dag_run']
        trans_id = dag_run.conf['transaction_id']
        routing_info = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="json_validation", key="route_info")
        new_file_path = routing_info['file_location']
        new_file_name = os.path.basename(routing_info['new_file_name'])
        file_path = os.path.join(new_file_path, new_file_name)
        batch_id = "123-AD-FF"
        dag_run_obj.payload = {'inputfilepath': file_path,
                               'transaction_id': trans_id,
                               'Id': batch_id}
```

The DAG runs all fine. In fact the python callable of the task mentioned until the last line. Then it errors out.

```
[2020-06-09 11:36:22,838] {taskinstance.py:1145} ERROR - No row was found for one()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 983, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py", line 95, in execute
    replace_microseconds=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 141, in trigger_dag
    replace_microseconds=replace_microseconds,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/api/common/experimental/trigger_dag.py", line 98, in _trigger_dag
    external_trigger=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dag.py", line 1471, in create_dagrun
    run.refresh_from_db()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models/dagrun.py", line 109, in refresh_from_db
    DR.run_id == self.run_id
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3446, in one
    raise orm_exc.NoResultFound("No row was found for one()")
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.NoResultFound: No row was found for one()
```

After which the `on_failure_callback` of that task is executed and all code of that callable runs perfectly ok as is expected. The query here is why did the dagrun_operator fail after the python callable.

**P.S** : The DAG that is being triggered by the `TriggerDagRunOperator` , in this case `dag_process_pos` starts with task of type`dummy_operator`

Comment: To add to my above post. It has so been found that when we remove `execution_date` parameter from the `TriggerDagRunOperator` it works. Is that a problem or change in the syntax. Also the Airflow-Dag examples provided with Airflow1.10.10 repository does not have a sample code for `Dagrun_Operator`